# Receiving media stream for Electron app on my react native app on the same network

Tags: node.js, webrtc, peerjs

I'm trying to send a media stream from Electron js to my react native mobile app.

I can connect to my localhost PeerJS Server and the two devices connect. I can send data using the .send() method:

```
conn.send("Message from electron")
```

When I try to send the stream, like this:

```
const call = peer.call(mobileId, newStream);
```

The mobile receives the call and the answer seems to work. However, this listener (for the stream) never executes and it seems like the stream never arrives:

```
mobPeer.on('call', function(call) {
   console.log("Web calling", call); // THIS WORKS FINE

   call.answer(null);
   call.on('stream', function(stream) {
       console.log('stream from desktop')  // THIS NEVER EXECUTES
   });
});
```

Is it because I'm trying to share a stream from getUserMedia and it needs to be over https? If so, anyway to get it to work when both devices are on the same network? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share your webrtc-internals dump?

Comment: Sorry, where am I getting this from? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Open `chrome://webrtc-internals/` in chrome. Run your scenario in another tab. Go back to `chrome://webrtc-internals/` tab, click create dump. Share the file.

Comment: Thanks. My app runs in electron, not the chrome browser (although I realise it's based on chromium), so guessing it doesn't work? I did try it but it looks like a pretty empty file.

Comment: I did not try with electron, but I guess this should work there as well, chromium should not be a problem, this is inside chromium engine. This should be something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZfnU.png

Comment: I've opened it in 1 tab, ran the app and started the stream but nothing appearing in the webrtc-internals tab. This is driving me crazy. Other people saying they got it working but don't appear to be doing anything different to me, other than I'm inside electron.

Comment: Would the output from {debug: 3} be any use?

Comment: I've read briefly on the electron. Sounds like you only have a possibility to log webrtc statistic. You can do smth like this```connection.getReceivers().forEach(receiver => {
          receiver.getStats().then(stats => {
            console.log(stats, receiver.track.kind);
          });``` Try to log and check what is in these logs. Or ask the question how to get webrtc statistic in electron.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Igor. It turns out to be a bug with the react-native-peerjs package. I'm not skilled up enough to work out what's wrong with it but hoping the author can help at some point.